# image not displaying cgridview

Tags: yii

seems straightforward but it's not showing the image... I've tried placing quotes in different places.

It gives me Property "CActiveDataProvider.product_image" is not defined.

I tried removing the path in 'value' and have it just the 'name', it shows the image name.
Also tried `'value'=> '$data-> product_image'`, that shows too (as string of course not as image). Not sure why it would show that error.

```
array(
   'name'=>'product_image',
   'type'=>'image',
   'value'=>'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath./images/thumbnail/thumb_'.$data->product_image.'))', ),
```

also tried the path with a variable

```
$thumb_path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/thumbnail/thumb_';
//stuff
   'name'=>'product_image',
   'type'=>'image',
   'value'=>'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->assetManager->publish('.$thumb_path.$data->product_image.'))',
```

Comment: I suggest you to add this kind of logic to model which is holding the data e.g add methods to model like `getProductThumb()`, `getProductImage()` etc and use those methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
array(
 'header'=>'product_image', // this will fix unknown property
 'type'=>'image',
 'value'=>'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->assetManager->publish("'.$thumb_path.$data->product_image.'"), // if it's pointing correctly, you have an image!
)',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
'name'=>'product_image',
'type'=>'html',
'value'=>'(!empty($data->product_image))?CHtml::image("' . Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/ImageFolderName/$data->product_image","",array("style"=>"width:25px;height:25px;")):CHtml::image("' . Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/no-image.jpg","")',
```

),